# How to access instance variable of component from handler method (of razorpay api) in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, this, razorpay

I am implementing Razorpay in my angular app.

I want to access the days variable from the handler function.
But it says property days does not exist.

this reference to the options object

```
days: any;

options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_1234567890", // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
    "amount": "", // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
    "currency": "INR",
    "name": "Acme Corp",
    "description": "Test Transaction",
    "image": "https://example.com/your_logo",
    "order_id": "", //This is a sample Order ID. Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
    "handler": function (response:any){
      SubscriptionPlanComponent.update_payment_to_paid(response,this.days); *****HERE*****
    },
    "prefill": {
        "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
        "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
        "contact": "9999999999"
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "Razorpay Corporate Office"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#3399cc"
    }
};

update_payment_to_paid(resp:any,days:any)
{
  ... ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
days: any;

options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_1234567890", // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
    "amount": "", // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
    "currency": "INR",
    "name": "Acme Corp",
    "description": "Test Transaction",
    "image": "https://example.com/your_logo",
    "order_id": "", //This is a sample Order ID. Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
    "handler": (response:any) => {
      SubscriptionPlanComponent.update_payment_to_paid(response,this.days); *****HERE*****
    },
    "prefill": {
        "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
        "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
        "contact": "9999999999"
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "Razorpay Corporate Office"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#3399cc"
    }
};
```

Comment: Is your issue solved? Any question?